# Why is my Filterizr gallery suddenly not working in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari

I have been using a Filterizr gallery for years on my website.

http://whataprettyface.ca (click 'portfolio' from the nav bar).

Recently I noticed (after not changing anything) that the gallery no longer works properly in Safari (desktop and mobile).

For some reason, selected galleries do not disappear when selecting another gallery.

Everything still works as it should in Firefox, Opera and Chrome.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Maybe it could be that Safari is not supported for windows anymore according to there own website. But check you console.log and see if you get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue.
I think the problem is Safari 15.4.
I solved it adding this css lines:

```
.filteredOut > a {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Nicola, that did the trick. Thanks. I noticed the outgoing gallery flickers before it reads the CSS but it's good enough for what I need it to do. Much appreciated.